# joining 4 tables together

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I wonder if anyone could help me.

I have 4 tables that need to be joined to retrieve the data i need.

**reviews**

**themes**

**reviewthemes**

**reviewsubthemes**

So i want to do a simple select * from reviews. With this i require the theme name from `themes` and the subtheme name from `themes`.

A review can have more than one theme and subtheme. Also a review may only have a theme with no subthemes and then another theme with subthemes.

`themes` table look like this

[image]

Both `reviewthemes` and `reviewsubthemes` look like this

[image]

reviews table looks like this:

[image]

I have tried but i am getting too confused.

So essentially the review table holds the reviews. The themes table is where the name of the themes are, and both reviewthemes and reviewsubthemes have a reviewID column to join with the `reviews` table and a themeID to joni to the `themes` table.

Does anyone know how to do this and also can you explain how the query is made.

Thanks

Comment: What does the `reviews` table look like?

Comment: @kalessin i have edited my question with the review table image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to do a `left join` using `reviews` as your left table and then match themes based on `themeid` from either one of the tables: `reviewthemes` or `reviewsubthemes`.

```
select r.*,
       t.name
from reviews r
left join reviewthemes rt on rt.reviewId = r.reviewId
left join reviewsubthemes rst on rst.reviewid = r.reviewid
left join themes t on (t.themeid = rt.themeid or t.themeid = rst.themeid)
```

You could also use `UNION` or `UNION ALL` to do this (preferable method):

```
select r.*,
       t.name
from reviews r
left join reviewthemes rt on rt.reviewId = r.reviewId
left join themes t on t.themeid = rt.themeid 

union all

select r.*,
       t.name
from reviews r
left join reviewsubthemes rst on rst.reviewid = r.reviewid
left join themes t on t.themeid = rst.themeid
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on your comments, here is the answer:

```
select r.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) as Name
from reviews r
left join reviewthemes rt on rt.reviewId = r.reviewId
left join reviewsubthemes rst on rst.reviewid = r.reviewid
left join themes t on (t.themeid = rt.themeid or t.themeid = rst.themeid)
group by r.*
```

Comment: I tried this, it does work but not exactly how i wanted it too. This only puts 1 theme on each row. So it could have the same review 5 times all exactly the same except for the theme name. Instead if a review has multiple themes or sub themes i need these to be on the same row in different columns. is this possible?

Comment: Look into `Group_Concat` if you want to put other themes/subthemes on the same row. Without sample data and expected output, it would be difficult to envision what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: well at the minute i have 5 rows with the same review. Everything is the same except for the theme column. Because there are 5 themes that link to this particular review it has made 5 different rows

Comment: Try this: `select r.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) as Name
from reviews r
left join reviewthemes rt on rt.reviewId = r.reviewId
left join reviewsubthemes rst on rst.reviewid = r.reviewid
left join themes t on (t.themeid = rt.themeid or t.themeid = rst.themeid)
group by r.*`

Comment: great that works exactly how i need it too :), however for some reason, im not sure if its how you have put the other tables names etc... but i tried to place this at the end of the query "where `reviews`.`categoryID` = 32".  it came back with Unknown column but if i do a simple statement it works just fine.

Comment: Cool! Try putting this before the `group by`:   `where r.categoryID = 32`

Comment: @MatthewSmart Why did you choose another answer?

Comment: aha i'm sorry, i must of not been paying attention to where i was clicking. I have changed it now :)

Comment: aha that would have been a little sad , someone helps and goes through the question, solves your problem.... then you vote someone else lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89309/discussion-between-futbolfan-and-matthew-smart).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't have the full picture but you might have too many tables, a themeID field in the Review table plus a theme/subtheme flag could have been enough.
Anyway, try this:

```
select r.*, t.name
  from reviews as r
  left join reviewthemes as rt on r.themeID = rt.themeID
  left join reviewsubthemes as rst on r.themeID = rst.themeID
  left join themes as t on r.themeID = t.themeID
```

This should work if it's the themeID field has the ID you want and not the ID field. Add more fields to the select as you wish.